# Compare arrays java

Tags: java, arrays

I have four arrays as follow.

1. Main String Array     - contains the words of a main string
2. User String Array    - contains the words of the user string
3. Missing words Array  - contains the missing words of the user string
4. Value Array          - contains the value of each word in the user string array

I have another empty array to assign new values. What I am doing is as below.

> 1. Compare each element in the main string with the corresponding element in the user string.
> 2. If the two elements are matching assign the corresponding element of value array to the new value array.
> 3. Else check whether the element is matching with the missing words array.
> 4. If it matches assign "0" to the corresponding element in the new value array.

What I have done up to now is given below.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mainStringArray.length; i++) {

        if (userStringArray[i].equals(mainWordsArray[i])){
           newvalueArray[i] = valueArray[i];
        }
        else {
            if (mainStringArray[i].equals(missingWordsArray[i])){
                newValueArray[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(mainStringArray[i] + " " + newValueArray[i]);
    }


  }
```

But I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the arrays are not same size. Please tell me a way to avoid this.

In a short way what I want is , I have a main string and a user string. Each word in the user string has a corresponding value and it is stored in the value array. I want to add those values to the words in the main string which can be found in the user string and 0 to the missing words.

Comment: You should avoid using arrays if you can and use ArrayList instead

Comment: that's the problem with arrays. They are not resizable. You should instead start looking at ArrayList's docs.

Comment: @Shervin if he uses the exact same method but with ArrayLists instead as you suggested, it will still give a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. try removing from an empty ArrayList. unless you check isEmpty of course.

Comment: i haven't looked throughly what you want to do. But have you tried the idea of using more loops. Some extra loops which will loop through the missingWordArray, and userStringArray?

Comment: what's so difficult adding `homework` tag>

Answer (score 1):

its a very simple solution: since you know that `userStringArray` is always gonna be lesser than or equal to the `mainStringArray`, you do the for loop over the `userStringArray`. you then need to take note of the length of the `userStringArray` using `userStringArray.length` and use that length value to get the part of the `mainStringArray` which has no corresponding elements in the `userStringArray` and proceed to do whatever you want to with these extra characters.

you may choose to use ArrayLists instead of arrays, but you will have to change your loop to account for removing values from an empty ArrayList by checking the `isEmpty()` condition. the rest of the logic can be the same.

**EDIT:**

this question is very ambiguous. as such, i shall roughly show you how to do the same thing as you wrote except with ArrayLists. the only tangible difference to the code is the checking of userStringArray.isEmpty().

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    ArrayList<Double> newValueArray = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Double> userStringArray = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Double> mainStringArray = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < mainStringArray.size(); i++) {
        if(!userStringArray.isEmpty){
           if (userStringArray.get(i).equals(mainWordsArray.get(i))){
              newvalueArray.remove(i);
              newvalueArray.add(i, valueArray.get(i));                
           } else {
              if (mainStringArray.get(i).equals(missingWordsArray.get(i))){
                 newValueArray.remove(i);
                 newValueArray.add(i, 0);
               }
           }

           System.out.println(mainStringArray[i] + " " + newValueArray.get(i));
        }


     }
```

Comment: I can't do this because the missing words are not according to an order. I have to find the missing words in the main string array and assign them the value as 0.

Comment: @gishu your question is very ambiguous. anyway, i've updated my code to reflect your original answer except using arraylists.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dhruv. Yes, the question is ambiguous.. My task is that I have a full string (main string) and incomplete one. (user string) I want to find the missing words (contain in the missing word array) in the user string and assign their value as 0. I will edit the question to show it more clearer.I tried your method, but I am using double values in the value array, and I got errors. Please help me.

Comment: @gishu for double, please change ArrayList<Integer> to ArrayList<Double>. im quite surprised you didn't guess this to be honest. note that "Double" is a class, which is related, but different from "double", which is a primitive type.

Comment: I am really sorry for that question, it sounds stupid.:) But my knowledge on collections is very poor. Now I get an error in the line, "newValueArray.remove(i) = 0;" as "Unexpected type required variable found value". Please give me some light on this.

Comment: @gishu that is because i mistyped the code. it should be newValueArray.remove(i). take out the "=0" part. but i'd seriously advice you to learn collections, its not very hard, and should be learnt if you want to go far in this field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dhruv. But I still  get the error, "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1". And thank you for your advice, I am on my way learning them as I realized the importance. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this case all the four arrays must be of the same size. So when you declare the arrays, simply make all their size as same. That will do.

Comment: I can't do this because arrays are made from two strings which are taken as the output of the user spoken words and a main string.